# How to round price in javascript? [Without Decimal]

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to round price like below :

`850,005,500` round to `850,006,000`. so my focus is on 4th / 5th number from right. More examples :

1. `55,000` round to `60,000` OR `50,000`
2. `846,000` round to `850,000`
3. `1,504,000` round to `1,500,000`
4. `1,556,000` round to `1,560,000`

So in above examples comas are not decimal, I'm just trying to split them for clear examples. How can i round this numbers up/down at 4th/5th position?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by using divide and then multiply.

```js
function roundPosition(n, pos) {
  const base = Math.pow(10, pos);
  return Math.round(n / base) * base;
}

console.log(roundPosition(154334, 4));  // round at position 4
console.log(roundPosition(154334, 5));  // round at position 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash module

```
var _ = require('lodash')
var number = 55000
_.round(number, -4)
_.round(number, -5)
```

To get floor value

```
_.floor(number, -4)
```

To get ceil value

```
_.ceil(number, -4)
```